# Ag-grid: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

Usingg ag-grid enterprise I receive the following
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

```
:Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at CellComp.afterCellRendererCreated (:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:274192)
    at :3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:259750
    at new AgPromise (:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:259711)
    at AgPromise.then (:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:259748)
    at createCellRendererFunc (:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:274164)
    at AnimationFrameService.executeFrame (:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:294524)
```

The error comes from the following part of the library:

```
        var cellRendererNotRequired = !this.isAlive() || cellRendererVersion !== this.cellRendererVersion;
        if (cellRendererNotRequired) {
            this.beans.context.destroyBean(cellRenderer);
            return;
        }
        this.cellRenderer = cellRenderer;
        this.cellRendererGui = this.cellRenderer.getGui();
        if (missing(this.cellRendererGui)) {
            return;
        }
        // if async components, then it's possible the user started editing since this call was made
        if (!this.editingCell) {
            **this.eCellValue.appendChild(this.cellRendererGui);**
        }
    };
```

**The cell renderer works when I return a string eg cellRenderer= () => `<span>123</span>` instead of react component cellRenderer= () => 123: **

Any ideas?
The error occured with React ag-grid version 25.3.0